# symfony 3.3 saving latitude and longutude google maps API

Tags: api, symfony, maps

I'm using google maps API and I need to save the position of each user after they select it by dragging the marker, knowing that they will be changing it from their profile and not an update page.

So basically I need to save the lat and lng of the user in the table right after they move marker, I haven't found a proper solution since we usually have regular forms with submit buttons to update. So here's the google maps div from the twig

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 380px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
      center:{
          lat: 45,
          lng: 45
      },
      zoom:15
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:{
          lat: 45,
          lng: 45
      },
      map: map,
      draggable: true
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function () {
      var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
      var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
      $('#lat').val(lat);
      $('#lng').val(lng);
  })

</script>
```

and here's the controller for the profil page

```
public function showEtabbAction(){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $etab = $this->getUser()->getEtablissement();

    $userNom = $this->getUser()->getNom();

    return $this->render('@AllforkidsUser/Etablissement/etab.html.twig',array("etablissement"=>$etab,"nom"=>$userNom));
}
```

and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put two hidden fields in your form and then on dragend map event, set the value of this hidden fields from the marker position. Then you can handle the request as a regular form.